# Get the maximum value in a group in mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

_how am I going to get its highest episode_id  in each anime_id

---this is my desired output

```
    |id  |episode_id |Anime_id
    |5   |    2      |  1
    |2   |    5      |  2
    |8   |    1      |  3
    |12  |    4      |  4
```

Comment: This is a *very* basic `group by` query.

Comment: `select anime_id,max(episode_id) as episode_id from your_table group by anime_id`

Comment: _but group by doesn't work either

Comment: _Thanks RubahMalam, it works now :D

Comment: @gordonlinoff the op appears to want the id too, so yes, it is 'basic', but 'very'??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Group by Query

```
select anime_id,max(episode_id) as episode_id from episode group by anime_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a roe number based on grouping of `anime_id` and sort by episode_id in descending order.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.episode_id, t1.anime_id from(
    select id, episode_id, anime_id,(
        case anime_id when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := anime_id end 
    ) as rn 
    from episode t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by anime_id, episode_id desc 
)t1 
where t1.rn = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72455/1)